# How to type Stateless Functional Component using styled-component in React-Native with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

Since one week we are using styled-component width React-Native and Typescript in my team project.

I'm forming myself on it and try to understand how to correctly use it with Typescript.

### My problem

I actually have problem to understand how am I supposed to type a Stateless Functional Component with styled method.

### Actual code

Here is what I have following the [doc](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components):

```js
const SFCView: SFC<{}> = (props) => {
  return <View style={props.style} />
}

const StyledSFCView = styled(SFCView)`
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
  background-color: green
`;
```

### My Error

Typescript says to me that props style does not exist in my type `SFC<{}>`. Indeed I defined it nowhere.

### What I tried

I tried to tell typescript that my `SFC` had those props

```js
const SFCView: SFC<{style: ViewStyle}> = (props) => {
  return <View style={props.style} />
}
```

But when I use `SFCView` somewhere else in my code typescript tell me that I have to specify all the props of a View.

Does anyone know how to correctly type it ?

Comment: Do you want props.style to override any style of StyledSFCView or just the styles you have on it currently i.e. width, height and background colour?

Comment: @BenSmith Just the style I have on it.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found the standard for web with **className**.

### My better solution for the moment

```js
import { SFC } from 'react';
import { StyleProp, ViewStyle } from 'react-native';

interface IProps {
 style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
}

const SFCView: SFC<IProps> = (props) => {
  return <View style={props.style} />
}

const StyledSFCView = styled(SFCView)`
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
  background-color: green
`;
```

**Advantages:**

- No more error about `style` prop in `SFCView`.
- `style` prop is optional so I have no error when I use `StyledSFCView`.

**Drawback:**

- `style` is optional and developper can define it when they use `StyledSFCView`.

Now this is the last point I have to clarify.

Comment: Remove the question mark if you want the style prop to be mandatory

Answer (score 0):

You can write `style(MyComponent)`, but for that to have an effect, you need to pass the prop `className`, provided by `styled-components`, to the final DOM element.

In your case, it should look something like this:

```
const StyledView = styled(View)`
  width: 100;
  height: 100;
  background-color: green;
`;

const View = ({ className, ... otherPropsYouMightHave }) => (
  // Whatever you have in this component
  <div className={className}>
    // Whatever View needs to render
  </div>
)
```

Edit: As you mentioned, `react-native` requires the prop `style` instead of `className`

Comment: Actually with React-Native we need to use `style` instead of `className` (doesn't exist for RN component).

Comment: You're right, react-native requires `style` instead of `className`
So your own answer is correct it seems, except that I believe `SFCView` to be superfluous, you can write `styled(View)` directly and have View handle the optional `style` prop
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components
Looks like